# Passing jQuery object into setTimeout recursive function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm attempting to pass in a jQuery object into a `setTimout` function, but to no avail.

This is what I currently have - It's working:

```
var checkIfElementsExist = function () {

    var elements = $('.myElements');

    if (elements.length) {
        console.log('els are here!');
        $(window.document).trigger('elementsExist', [elements]);

    } else {
        console.log('nope, check it again');
        setTimeout(checkIfElementsExist, 500);
    }

}

checkIfElementsExist();
```

But as soon as I take `$('.myElements')` out of the function, and try passing it into the function as an argument, `elements.length` always returns zero.

```
var checkIfElementsExist = function (elements) {

    if (elements.length) {
        console.log('els are here!');
        $(window.document).trigger('elementsExist', [elements]);

    } else {
        console.log('nope, check it again');
        setTimeout(checkIfElementsExist, 500);
    }

}

checkIfElementsExist($('.myElements'));
```

I read that you cannot pass in arguments into the `setTimeout` function, so I attempted to pass elements as an additional argument into the `setTimeout` call e.g. `setTimout(checkIfElementsExist, 500, elements);`, but still nothing.

UPDATE:

I've made the update that Pointy mentioned, but it still appears to not work. Here is a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/z4nsx8qb/) to better illustrate the problem.

Comment: `setTimeout(function() { checkIfElementsExist(elements); }, 500);`

Comment: Also: `setTimeout('checkIfElementsExist(elements)', 500);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of

```
    setTimeout(checkIfElementsExist, 500);
```

you can do this:

```
    setTimeout(function( ) { checkIfElementsExist(".myElements"); }, 500);
```

By wrapping an anonymous function around your actual function, you can pass in whatever arguments you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my code, but it still doesn't appear to be working correctly. I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z4nsx8qb/) to help illustrate the issue.

Comment: @Blexy Because you only construct the jQuery object *once*, it won't update when the DOM changes. [Here is an updated version of your fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5o1r4x0w/1/)

Comment: Ah! So cache the selector and then on subsequent checks, reference the cached selector. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Executing `$('.myElements')` traverses the DOM and returns an array of all elements with `class="myElements"`.

When you pass `$('.myElements')` initially, you are only constructing that array the first time. The following proceeding times you are not passing any arguments.

The real question here is why are `.myElements` not loaded when your script is loaded? Are they created dynamically? If not, your script should be wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){ // ... code here })` to wait for the full page to be loaded.